# Getting 0's and NAs for my t-test p-values

Tags: statistics, data-science, networkx

I have a data table of centrality measures for a crypto transaction networks for USDC and USDT. I am trying to see if the average level of a given centrality measure in one network is different than. The thought being that, for example, if the average level of closeness centrality is higher in one network than the other then it's an overall closer network.

The issue is that when I run some of the statistical tests, I get NaNs and 0's for by p-values. You can see an example of the code and data below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]